# What does /ChainingPackage do?

Tags: windows, batch-file, powershell

I am installing .net framework 4.5 on remote PC for upgrading powershell 4 from CMD.

```
"%PathToInstaller%\NDP451-KB2858728-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" /q /norestart /log %log%\.net4.5installLog.htm
```

I see some people doing this with a `/ChainingPackage` switch, just wondering what does this do? Cuz I dont see this option in `/?`

Comment: There was this (closed / unfixed) request to clarify the documentation: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/9933

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/ChainingPackage` switch is being used when an application is installed together with .Net framework. As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#chaining):

> If you're creating a custom setup program for your app, you can chain
>   (include) the .NET Framework setup process in your app's setup
>   process.

Comment: That just says you can do it, not what it does.

Comment: I agree, this doesn't actually answer the question

Answer (score 4):

Per the MSDN page linked by vonPryz

> "Specifies the name of the executable that is doing the chaining. This
> information is sent to Microsoft as anonymous feedback to help improve
> future deployment experiences."

I think it's critical to know this and I choose not to do it.

Comment: Does it care what the "executable" string actually contains? Could it just be any text?